# Link to Ubuntu .a Module Library from GPS?

Tags: ubuntu, ada, gnat

I have a GNAT Programming Studio (GPS)/GNAT project on an Ubuntu system.  The project's Ada content compiles just fine; however, I need to bind and link to an external ".a" library, which contains (C++) routines pragma Imported by the Ada software.  Every time I try, I receive the message "a library project can not have main specified."

I don't consider my project a "library project" -- I just want to link to the library.  Why is this so difficult?  Is it possible to do without recreating the world?

Alert:  I am not a Linux hack, so please explain clearly with example.  Thanks  :-)

Comment: The error lies probably in your .gpr project file. Can you post its contents?

Comment: Probably can't post it, but thanks for the clue.  Btw, I do notice that somethings set by GPS do not get unset, when they are changed through GPS, so you may well be correct.

Comment: @Eryndlia: After updating properties via GPS, be sure to do a "Project/Save All" to get them into the gpr file.

Answer (score 1):

You may be misinterpreting the "Library" tab on the "Edit Project Properties" dialog. You fill that out when your project is to be built as a library. So blank it out.

Then on the Switches tab/Gnatmake tab, in the bottom text box add the "-llib" references to the libraries you need to link with. E.g.:

```
-lmycpplib -lyourcpplib -lcppisnotforme
```

Comment: You may need to tell the linker where the non-standard library is; precede the `-lmycpplib` with `-L/where/to/find/it`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Marc C's advice, if it's a "magic" library (ie -lz to link to zlib, -lm to link to math, etc) you should copy the file into GCC's external lib folder:

`\lib\gcc\i686-pc-mingw32\4.5.3\` on my windows GNAT directory, though linux should have some similar structure.

Comment: Pretty sure that’s an ‘internal’ lib folder; the more normal place would probably be {GNAT top dir}\lib.

Comment: Not sure I understand these comments, but this library is created locally -- not part of any distribution.